# Django | Admin display foreign key as field rather than object

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project with the following two models setup:

```
class List(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class ListItem(models.Model):
    team_list = models.ForeignKey(List, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
    index = models.IntegerField()
```

I have them registered in my admin as follows:

```
class ListAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('team_name', 'name')

    def team_name(self, obj):
        return obj.team.name


admin.site.register(List, ListAdmin)


class ListItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('team', 'team_list_name', 'index')

    def team(self, obj):
        return obj.team_list.team.name

    def team_list_name(self, obj):
        return obj.team_list.name


admin.site.register(ListItem, ListItemAdmin)
```

This is great because now when I am looking at all of my "List items" in Django Admin, I can readily see the name of the list each item belongs to.

However, when I am adding a new list item in admin I can only view the lists as an object (EX: "List Object (1)").  How can I make it so that the dropdown menus for foreign keys will display an object field rather than the object type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string used in the drop-down will come from the `__str__` method in the relevant object. So to correct this, all you need to do is update your model:

```
class List(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        # Return a string that represents the instance
        return f"List {self.name}"
```